# Country geolocation redirects me to the wrong link?

Tags: php, redirect, geolocation, geo

So I have this code and my ip is from the country ph;

```
<?php
require_once('geoip.inc');

$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

switch ($country) {
 case 'ph':
     $location = 'url/ph/index.php';
     break;
 case 'us':
     $location = 'url/intl/index.php';
     break;
 case 'in':
     $location = 'url/intl/index.php';
     break;
 default:
     $location = 'url/intl/index.php';
     break;
 }
 header('Location: '.$location.'');
 ?>
```

whenever i try to access my site with that code and using my own home ip (philippines) it keeps on redirecting me on the intl/index.php page. Everything is in my home directory already like the geoip.inc and geoip.dat. Both of them are in the root folder already.

Anyone know what im missing here? Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified what $country to resolves to? Try echoing/dumping/logging that variable.

Comment: @aynber hmm sorry but how can I log it? really new into this things.

Comment: If you have some sort of logging function, use it. Otherwise, do `var_dump($country)` to make sure you're getting what you're expecting.

Comment: @aynber i deleted my previous comment, but i managed to log it, and it says "US" tho. 1:blah 2:blahstring(2) "US"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function geoip_country_code_by_addr is returning country code in upper case so PH, US, IN etc. and when you put in switch lowercase country codes always it includes default data.

So need to change contry codes to uppercase like

```
<?php
require_once('geoip.inc');

$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

switch ($country) {
 case 'PH':
     $location = 'url/ph/index.php';
     break;
 case 'US':
     $location = 'url/intl/index.php';
     break;
 case 'IN':
     $location = 'url/intl/index.php';
     break;
 default:
     $location = 'url/intl/index.php';
     break;
 }
 header('Location: '.$location.'');
 ?>
```

Comment: tried it but it still redirects me to the intl page.

Comment: @Sync Please add before switch var_dump($country); and post us a result.

Comment: I got this from var dump; string(2) "US"

Comment: @Sync so your IP is from US not PH and switch is correctly loading intl version. Please look here what country is provided on this website for your IP http://www.checkip.com/

Comment: That's really weird, because 100% accurate my ip is from ph;
Country:  Philippines

Comment: @Sync so var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); and check is this the same IP as shown on website I provide

Comment: That's weird, it gave me a different ip. and it's from the us. But whenever i check my ip using checkip.com its ph ip

Comment: it gave me cloudflare's ip. Maybe it's conflicting with cloudflare or not?

Comment: @Sync this is normal when using cloudflare because you need to install additional package on your server https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads/ and check first tab about logging real user IP and then your script should work, before it should always return US for any visitor

Comment: oh I see, i'll just install it then. Thanks for the help and this awesome answer.